# nativescript angular app silently crash using firebase on ios

Tags: ios, nativescript-angular, nativescript-firebase

I run this command `tns run ios --device "iPhone 11"`

and get

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Successfully transferred bundle.875fd225a41f2a304241.hot-update.js on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Successfully transferred 875fd225a41f2a304241.hot-update.json on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Successfully transferred bundle.js on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Successfully transferred inspector_modules.js on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64.
Restarting application on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64...
(RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Identity resolved as application<org.nativescript.myapp>
(UserNotifications) [com.apple.UserNotifications:Connections] [org.nativescript.myapp] Creating a user notification center
CONSOLE INFO: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
(RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Identity resolved as application<org.nativescript.myapp>
(UserNotifications) [com.apple.UserNotifications:Connections] [org.nativescript.myapp] Creating a user notification center
CONSOLE INFO: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
NativeScript debugger has opened inspector socket on port 18183 for org.nativescript.myapp.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:18183
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 18183
}
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.myapp on device B6B5FD06-ACB6-4E36-9071-2B0BE89CCF64
```

my app just silently crashes without error messages the only one I get is a connection error from socket. Couldn't find anything about it on the net. At this moment I wasn't able to init a simple hello world app with a firebase initialisation

I'm running

```
nativescript version 7.0.10
XCode Version 12.0.1
```

and

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.3",
    "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~10.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.0"
  },
```

my angular code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { firebase } from "@nativescript/firebase"; 

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
        firebase.init({
          // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
          // see their respective docs.
        }).then(
          () => {
            console.log("firebase.init done");
          },
          error => {
            console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
          }
        );
    }
}
```

I'm stuck so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried running it in XCode? If I get silent crashes, I run it from XCode and usually get an error message there.

Comment: @agritton could you describe a bit how this could be done? please. this is not urgent

Comment: From XCode open the <yourappname>.xcworkspace file located in the platforms/ios folder. Then you can click the run button from XCode.

Comment: @agritton I'll test later thanks